# postgresql how to insert a value with double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: postgresql

This is the sql code that I run on my postgresql database. It turns out to cause errors

```
INSERT INTO t1(
   group1
)
VALUES
("GIRL''S 16'" AND LESS BIKE");
```

but if I delete the double quotes after 16', it works fine.
So I wonder is there a way to keep the double quote inside but also insert successfully into the table?

Comment: String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes. Double quote do not need to be escaped. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it will work fine if you remove one of the `"`, as that would be illegal SQL.

Strings always have to be surrounded by single quotes (`'`); a double quote (`"`) has no special meaning.

This would be a correct string:

```
'GIRL''S 16" AND LESS BIKE'
```

except that would really be for large girls.

Answer (score 4):

What about using [dollar-quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)?

```
SELECT $$GIRL'S 16" AND LESS BIKE$$
```

> Notice that inside the dollar-quoted string, single quotes can be used
>   without needing to be escaped. Indeed, no characters inside a
>   dollar-quoted string are ever escaped: the string content is always
>   written literally. Backslashes are not special, and neither are dollar
>   signs, unless they are part of a sequence matching the opening tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just encapsulate whatever text you need in double quotes under single quotes.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO t1
(group1)
VALUES
('"GIRL S 16" AND LESS BIKE');
```